# Problem with more than one light node peer connection

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, peers

I have the following nodes running :

FULL NODE and LIGHT SERVER

```
geth --datadir node1 --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 3003 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --ipcpath node1/geth.ipc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 15 --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsport 3103 --wsorigins "*" --lightserv 80
```

LIGHT NODE

```
geth --datadir node2 --port 30304 --rpc --rpcport 3004 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.2 --ipcpath node2/geth.ipc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 15 --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.2 --wsport 3104 --wsorigins "*" --syncmode light
```

LIGHT NODE

```
geth --datadir node3 --port 30305 --rpc --rpcport 3005 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.2 --ipcpath node3/geth.ipc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 15 --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.2 --wsport 3105 --wsorigins "*" --syncmode light
```

Node2 is a peer of Node1 and everything works correcty, but Node3 cannot connect to the fullnode and I get the following error:

```
Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="peer is unknown or unhealthy"
```

Using --verbosity 6 :

```
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.459] Adding p2p peer                          name=Geth/v1.8.19-stable-... addr=127.0.0.1:30301 peers=1
TRACE[02-10|22:23:18.459] connection set up                        id=6e6521711faf66d0 addr=127.0.0.1:30301 conn=staticdial                              inbound=false
TRACE[02-10|22:23:18.459] Starting protocol les/2                  id=6e6521711faf66d0 conn=staticdial
TRACE[02-10|22:23:18.459] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 6e6521711faf66d0 127.0.0.1:30301"
TRACE[02-10|22:23:18.459] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (29.977287427s)"
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.459] Connect new entry                        enode=6e6521711faf66d0
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.459] Light Ethereum peer connected            id=6e6521711faf66d0 conn=staticdial                              name=Geth/v1.8.19-stable
TRACE[02-10|22:23:18.466] Registering sync peer                    peer=6e6521711faf66d0
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.466] Received new announcement                id=6e6521711faf66d0 conn=staticdial                              number=10494 hash= reorg=0
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.466] Registered new entry                     enode=6e6521711faf66d0
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.466] Light Ethereum message handling failed   id=6e6521711faf66d0 conn=staticdial                              err=EOF
TRACE[02-10|22:23:18.466] Unregistering sync peer                  peer=6e6521711faf66d0
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.466] Disconnected old entry                   enode=6e6521711faf66d0
DEBUG[02-10|22:23:18.466] Removing p2p peer                        id=6e6521711faf66d0 conn=staticdial                              duration=7.280ms peers=0 req=true err="too many peers"
```

It seems like it is possible to connect just one light node. Any idea how to solve it?